# How to set UITextField in UINavigationBar sizeToFit?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

I have been unable to find a solution to this issue. I am unable to give the UITextField, `textField`, a `sizeToFit` property when placed in the UINavigationBar.

I have tried: `textField.sizeToFit()`

And of course the Interface Builder doesn't give any options when put into the UINavigationBar. Any solutions would be awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an outlet to your `textField` and then just call this function in `viewDidLoad`(you could also paste the code below directly in `viewDidLoad`):

```
func setWidth() {
    var frame: CGRect = self.textField.frame
    frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
    self.textField.frame = frame
}
```

**Results:**
iPhone 6S Plus:
[image]

iPhone 6:
[image]

iPhone 5:
[image]

**Update**
To change the size on rotation add the following lines of code:

In `viewDidLoad` add this observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Add this function that will detect the orientation and then resize the `textField`:

```
func rotated(){
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
        print("landscape")
        setWidth()
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
        print("Portrait")
        setWidth()
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work upon rotating landscape. **Edit:** [Project.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8yxsnf2jojanmc/WiBlaze.zip?dl=0). The project is quite literally five lines of code, haha.

Comment: @MattSwift, check the updated code that will detect orientation change too.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help! It's working perfectly now. I've been looking for a solid solution to this for a while now. You have finally helped me find that solution. :)